# How to use array string in react-intl?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, translation, react-intl

Is there any option to show translation from array string ?

```
"app.components.TeaserContent.kooy":["your personal selection.", "outfits styled for you.", "new favourite items.", "your new wardrobe."]
```

for

```
import { defineMessages } from 'react-intl'
export default defineMessages({
  typeText: {
    id: 'app.components.TeaserContent.kooy',
    default: 'dfgdfgdf'
  },

console.log(intl.formatMessage({ ...messages.typeText }))
```

and getting error in console same as in the question

[image: screenshot 2019-01-18 at 2 48 43 pm]